# NativeScript - TNSPhone.dail() is not working for iphone

Tags: android, iphone, nativescript

import * as TNSPhone from "nativescript-phone";

TNSPhone.dial(num, false);

Used this permission in info.plist

```
<key>LSApplicationQueriesSchemes</key>
<array>
<string>tel</string>
<string>telprompt</string>
</array>
```

Its working for android device.

Comment: Try [utils](https://docs.nativescript.org/core-concepts/utils#openurl-function) -`utils.openUrl("tel:123456789")`;

Comment: Did Not worked, openUrl works for utils.openUrl("https://docs.nativescript.org/core-concepts/utils")

Comment: Did you try a clean build after updating `LSApplicationQueriesSchemes`?

Comment: yes, no progress

Comment: May I know which device you are using for testing?